# multiplying cells and sum then for a range

Tags: excel, formula

In my excel template, I need to have a formula to multiply two numbers with 2 or 3 conditions, and then sum the found numbers in an area.

For example;

```
First range is; AI22:AI1100
Second range is; AB22:AB1100
Third range is; N22:N1100
Fourt range is; K22:K1100
```

For first formula, i need to check the second range, found the cells that contain the same value as A2, then get the row number, find the value of the first range/that row cell, then divide it to its fourth range, and go on like this till AB1100 and sum all of that found numbers.

For second formula, i need to check the second range, found the cells that contain the same value as A2, then get the row number, check the third range if its the same value as A3, if it is then find the value of the first range/that row cell, then divide it to its fourth range, and go on like this till AB1100 and sum all of that found numbers.

I tried those with sumproduct, but it only sums both ranges and divides them in the end.

I can write this in Vba, but I need to store the values in the worksheets, so it will be better if I can do this in a formula.

I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You want SUM() as an Array formula

```
=SUM(IFERROR((AB22:AB1100 = A2)*(AI22:AI1100)/(K22:K1100),0))
```

And:

```
=SUM(IFERROR((AB22:AB1100 = A2)*(N22:N1100 = A3)*(AI22:AI1100)/(K22:K1100),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting Edit mode.

Comment: Yeah, both second and third ranges are text. AB, an N columns.

Comment: Sorry I meant the `(AI22:AI1100)/(K22:K1100)` ranges not the other two.  They are okay as text.

Comment: Then how are you dividing it into numbers?  You stated you want to divide `AI22:AI1100` by `K22:K1100` you can't divide numbers by text.

Comment: Sorry, rows AI and K are all numbers not texts. But still this formula gives me "divided by zero" error.

Comment: Both AI and K columns have numbers. This shouldn't be zero

Comment: Then you have `0` or blanks which Excel sees as `0` in K and you cannot divide by `0`.

Comment: not all rows have number, but if, AB column has the matching value, both of other columns have number. This is actually just a test sheet, I have 3 rows which contains numbers, but still not working correctly.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the edited version gives 0. It thinks that there is an error. It normally give me 19,17.... I checked it with changing the ranges of your first formula. But I can't change the range, because there are hundreds of different worksheets with different ranges with max of 1100.